# TRANSMITIR VIDEO LOCAL CON PYCHROMECAST

Tags: python

Quiero transimitir un video .mp4 a mi chromecast usando pychromecast, como se hace? Solo se pueden enviar videos con la url de este, pero no archivos locales como '/resources/video.mp4'. ¿Alguien que sepa hacerlo?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hasta donde yo se no puedes directamente, pero siempre puedes crear un servidor http local. Puedes empezar creando un servidor básico con python usando [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html), para pruebas o si es un proyecto personal sencillo puede bastar, antes de pensar en apache, lighttpd, etc